To cut and download part of video from vk.com
I try to cut and download part of an online video from vk.com, using yt-dlp and ffmpeg, in one step.
I tried

ffmpeg $(yt-dlp -g 'https://vk.com/video302700968_456241462' | sed 's/^/-ss 05:00 -i /') -t 00:30 -c copy output.mkv and

ffmpeg -ss 00:05:00 -to 00:05:30 -i "$(yt-dlp --get-url 'https://vk.com/video302700968_456241462')" -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4


But either command returns Error opening input files: Server returned 400 Bad Request.
How to make it work?
The video was created in 1916 and is not protected by copyright.

What are you trying to achieve? Extract just 30 seconds from 5m00s until 5m30s? My first suggestion is to just download a complete version of the file, and then extract the portion you're interested in locally.

"My first suggestion is to just download a complete version of the file, and then extract the portion you're interested in locally." - I want to do it one step, without downloading a complete version.

yt-dlp uses ffmpeg behind the scenes for you, and provides the --download-sections ... argument for exactly this purpose.

--download-sections REGEX:
Download only chapters that match the regular expression. A "*" prefix denotes time-range instead of chapter. Negative timestamps are calculated from the end. "*from-url" can be used to download between the "start_time" and "end_time" extracted from the URL. Needs ffmpeg. This option can be used multiple times to download multiple sections, e.g. --download-sections "*10:15-inf" --download-sections "intro"

yt-dlp --download-sections '*5:00-5:30' https://vk.com/video302700968_456241462

The seeks will likely be inaccurate, so you may have to trim further - I got a 32 second clip starting with someone wedged in a ladder.

The URL returned is signed, so any change the the request might be considered invalid (including User Agent, Range, etc...) - instead, get yt-dlp to provide the relevant access for you.
Using sed is not relevant or appropriate here.
